# Returning value of function containing a Promise

Tags: node.js

I want to be *informed* about a user's login status. For example, if a user attempts to sign up using an existing email in the database, I want to get a return value of `STATUS_DUPLICATE_EMAIL` (a string). Another possibility is if a user attempts to sign in with an email with a previously logged in social media account, I want to get a return value of `STATUS_SNS_EMAIL`.

Code snippet:

```
app.post("/api/signup", (req, res) => {
   const status = checkEmail(req, res);
   // some sign up logic...
}

...
checkEmail = (req, res) => {
   Database.findOne({ 
      where: {
         email: req.body.email
      }
   }).then((user) => {
      if (user) {
          res.status(400).send({ message: "Email already used." });
      }
   
   return STATUS_DUPLICATE_EMAIL;
}
```

When I try to `console.log` `status`, it is `undefined`, and I'm not sure why so. What is the general way to get a return value from a function like `checkEmail`?

Comment: The only good way to deal with it is by using `async await `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `status` is the value the function `checkEmail()` returns - which is currently nothing.
What you should do is return your promise (Database.findOne) from your `checkEmail`.
Now the value of status will be the promise your returned.
Now you should call it's method `then` again to get the value.

The promise is resolved but the Javascript engine reads your code before it is. Therefore, the method `then` of a promise returns a promise as well.

```js
app.post("/api/signup", (req, res) => {
  checkEmail(req, res).then(desired_value => {
    const status = desired_value;
  }
}

...
checkEmail = (req, res) => {
   return Database.findOne({ 
      where: {
         email: req.body.email
      }
   }).then((user) => {
      if (user) {
          res.status(400).send({ message: "Email already used." });
      }
   
      return STATUS_DUPLICATE_EMAIL;
   }
}
```

#### Alternatively

You can use `async/await` pattern. When declaring a function as `async` you can prefix promises inside it with `await` which will block the code execution until it's resolved.

```js
app.post("/api/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const status = await checkEmail(req, res);
}

...
checkEmail = (req, res) => {
   return Database.findOne({ 
      where: {
         email: req.body.email
      }
   }).then((user) => {
      if (user) {
          res.status(400).send({ message: "Email already used." });
      }
   
      return STATUS_DUPLICATE_EMAIL;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, "The value of status is the value the function checkEmail() returns - which is currently nothing."! This line is very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should return `Database.findOne()`.

Also use `async await` to get the result of `checkMail()`.

```
app.post("/api/signup", async (req, res) => {
   const status = await checkEmail(req, res);
   // some sign up logic...
}
...
app.post("/api/signup", (req, res) => {
   const status = checkEmail(req, res);
   // some sign up logic...
}

...
checkEmail = (req, res) => {
   return Database.findOne({ 
      where: {
         email: req.body.email
      }
   }).then((user) => {
      if (user) {
          res.status(400).send({ message: "Email already used." });
      }
   
      return STATUS_DUPLICATE_EMAIL;
   }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, do you know what's the rationale behind this? I understand that doing so returns a Promise, but am I not already "waiting" for the Database promise to resolve before returning a value?

Comment: Just updated, use async await to get the result of checkMail